# Access alias in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to access an alias from the outer query in the subquery, like this code. Except it is not working. Is there a way to do this?
My goal is to make these aggregate functions for every OwnerIdName and this is the only way I can think of.
I am working in SQL Server 2008.

Thanks

```
SELECT Incident.OwnerIdName as OIN
  ,(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Incident 
    WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN '2011/1/1' AND '2011/1/31'
    AND Incident.OwnerIdName = OIN ) as CasesOpened
  ,(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM IncidentResolution 
    WHERE ActualEnd BETWEEN '2011/1/1' AND '2011/1/31'
            AND Incident.OwnerIdName = OIN ) as CasesClosed
FROM Incident
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you use the column name directly..? Like..

```
SELECT Inc.OwnerIdName as OIN
  ,(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Incident 
    WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN '2011/1/1' AND '2011/1/31'
    AND Incident.OwnerIdName = Inc.OwnerIdName ) as CasesOpened
  ,(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM IncidentResolution 
    WHERE ActualEnd BETWEEN '2011/1/1' AND '2011/1/31'
            AND Incident.OwnerIdName = Inc.OwnerIdName ) as CasesClosed
FROM Incident Inc
```

If you want to use the Alias directly, you will have to do that early on in your query and then use it for all the Scalar Sub-Queries..

```
SELECT INC.OIN
  ,(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Incident 
    WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN '2011/1/1' AND '2011/1/31'
    AND Incident.OwnerIdName = INC.OIN ) as CasesOpened
  ,(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM IncidentResolution 
    WHERE ActualEnd BETWEEN '2011/1/1' AND '2011/1/31'
            AND Incident.OwnerIdName = INC.OIN ) as CasesClosed
from 
(Select OwnerIdName OIN
  FROM Incident) INc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this(works for >= SQL 2005):

```
WITH 
    CreatedQry AS
    (
        SELECT OwnerIdName, COUNT(1) AS CreatedCount
          FROM  Incident 
        WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN '2011/1/1' AND '2011/1/31'
    ),
    EndQry AS
    (
        SELECT OwnerIdName, COUNT(1) AS EndCount
          FROM  IncidentResolution  
        WHERE ActualEnd  BETWEEN '2011/1/1' AND '2011/1/31'
    )
    SELECT  CreatedQry.OwnerIdName, CreatedCount, EndCount
      FROM  CreatedQry LEFT JOIN EndQry
        ON  CreatedQry.OwnerIdName = EndQry.OwnerIdName
```